# Bulk update + SQL + self join

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to update a column in Table with reference to other column(s) in same table.

Ex: As in figure below - I would like to update effective endate with min date whichever is greater than effective Start Date of currrent record.

How can this be acheived in T-SQL.  Can this be done with single update statement ?

[alt text http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/1448/updateenddate.jpg](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/1448/updateenddate.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using a subselect, something like the following:

```
UPDATE MyTable mt
SET mt.EFFECTIVE_END_DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(mt2.EFFECTIVE_START_DATETIME)
                                 FROM MyTable mt2
                                 WHERE mt2.EFFECTIVE_START_DATETIME > mt.EFFECTIVE_START_DATETIME);
```

Comment: Thanks Lc,  it worked changed it as 
UPDATE  T0
SET     T0.EFFECTIVE_END_DATETIME = ( SELECT    ISNULL(MIN(T1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATETIME),'9999-12-31')
                                      FROM       SHARED.OSP_GEO_BOUNDARY_DIM T1
                                      WHERE     T1.EFFECTIVE_START_DATETIME > T0.EFFECTIVE_START_DATETIME
                                                AND T0.OSP_nk = T1.OSP_NK
                                    )
FROM     SHARED.OSP_GEO_BOUNDARY_DIM T0

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you want can be accomplished with a case statement, but I can't give you code because the following part of your question makes no sense:

> update effective endate with min date whichever is greater than effective Start Date of currrent record.

Comment: Hello Joel,  min date mean min start date for given NK that is greater than current record start date.  Thanks